# Show loading (placeholder) image when Block loads on Viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, viewport

*I've searched for an answer to this question but always find an answer that doesn't exactly solve my problem.*

I want to show a "loading" image for 4 seconds before the content of the div is actually loaded. I cannot figure it out.

[HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/och42noo/9/)

```
<div class='main-slider'>
<div> <!-- Content -->
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-gk6rnMRH9qE/VXJ40BWuC4I/AAAAAAAABZs/BWesiVwBgfg/s1050/camera-girl-nikon-photography-Favim.com-205093.jpg"/>
</div>
</div> <!--main-slider end-->
```

I want to do this like [this example site](http://tinyurl.com/nzob4ls). On this site block loads when a block on Viewport and show loader image for few second, is there any way or jQuery plugin to do this.

Answer (score 1):

So, you would first give your container div `position: relative;`. Then, you would need to add a div inside your container, lets say `<div class="overlay"></div>`. Your overlay's css is something like...

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Then, with a little js (I used jquery here)...

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

Edit: you may also need to play with `z-index` on your overlay.